# Reading browser log from protractor yields no results after second call

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I'm trying to detect if a certain warning is logged in the console for a third-party API, which happens at a variable point in time. What I want to do is to **read out the browser log repeatedly until I have found the log I am looking for.** For brevity, this is just a similar case, but easier to read:

```
browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(logs){
    console.log('initial logged statements: ', logs.length);
    // yields some console messages which are expected
});

browser.sleep(1000).then(function(){
    browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(logs){
        console.log('reading browserlog after 1 second', logs.length);
        // yields no console messages
    });
});
```

Even though I have hard coded a `console.error('test')` in the rendered page after 500 ms, the second call to `browser.manager().logs().get('browser')`yields no results at all. Has someone an idea why this doesn't work?

[The Protractor documentation](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.Logs.prototype.get) says that after every call the buffer is cleared, and that the new call only renders the new console logs since the last call (which is exactly what I need).

Comment: What if you would increase the sleep delay - any difference? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe Nope, however, I have created an issue at protractor github and it is confirmed bug. I will answer my question with a link reference. Thanks for your interests though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been an [confirmed bug](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1914) at Selenium. So fortunately it's not my code, it is reproduceable by others as well.